# How to make Android app that 'eats' the RAM memory

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, ram

I know this sound crazy but is not :)

I have an application that gets killed when run on mobile phones that have low ram memory.
To test this app I need something that 'eats' the RAM, I do this so far by starting a lot of games , opening apps , pressing home button and on just to eat the RAM memory...

So I thing it is stupid to waste 10-20 minutes just to fill the RAM memory with 'garbage' and maybe there is way to do this with some other dummy app that I will use just to 'eat' the RAM memory on the phone , so my other app will get killed by android system...

Does anybody have this problem so far ? and is it possible to do this with one app ?
Is it possible to eat a lot of ram memory just from one application ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using emulator with low memory settings?

Comment: I need an real device :( , emulator is not an option , I know that I can set the AVD settings as I please but that can help me for this situation

Comment: create a few apps with different package names but same code that uses a bit of memory, but keeps some background thread running until you click a button to make it stop.  Make sure the background thread is accessing a large memory object (like big images).  You can only hog so much memory with one app so you will need a few of them.

Comment: Can you root the device? Maybe then you could, using some dumb C program, allocate much memory?

Comment: I think you should see this http://www.testingdiaries.com/test-android-app-low-memory/

Answer (score 5):

Faced with same problem (need to fill RAM memory on device until my application die)
By chance found a program in google market for that :)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.empirical.android.application.fillmemory

Comment: This app was unfortunately removed from the Play Store, even though it is extremely useful for app development.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small free application which does exactly what you want. And it's free, without ads or permissions :)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fabsimilian.memorypump

Comment: could you please share the source code of your app.

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a wild guess here but create an application with one activity class, one abstract service class and several concrete services extending the abstract one.

The abstract service class will eat memory, you can make something as simple as loading the same bitmap from the resources and putting it into a LruCache, sleep for a a few miliseconds and repeat.

Then you'll create several services class that extends the abstract, but require no further code, just

```
public class MemoryEaterService_01 extends AbstractMemoryEaterService{}
```

Now from the activity launch you'll do the obvious thing of firing the services.

now the clever part starts, on the manifest you'll declare each one of those services in a different process (basically starting each one of the services in a different VM with its own heap memory) like this:

```
<service android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true"
     android:name="memoryEater_01"
     android:process="com.yourpackage.memory_eater_01" >
</service>
```

and if you try it, please let me know if it works, I'm very curious about it.

Answer (score 0):

in command prompt, type the following to get all processes with their priority (nice)

eg : cmd >adb shell ps -p

so take one process and renice its priority to some value (range -20 to +20) lesser value has more priority.

eg :  adb shell renice -20 782  [adb shell renice  ]
by this way we can let that process to eat more memory, by this way

Answer (score 0):

Just load huge Bitmaps into List in cycle or show them in views if You want.